# sqitch init snowflake cannot determine Snowflake account name

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sqitch

I'm following the sqitchtutorial-snowflake tutorial and getting stuck when initializing a sqitch project

When i run `sqitch init widgets --engine snowflake`

The terminal indicates, "Cannot determine Snowflake account name"

Comment: Could you please share the error, by seeing the error seems account name is invalid.

Comment: @Sriga - where is sqitch getting an account name from?

Comment: By checking sqitch documentation page it is recommended to use project URI like below:
sqitch init flipr --uri https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch-snowflake-intro/ --engine snowflake
You can refer the documentation page using below link:
https://sqitch.org/docs/manual/sqitchtutorial-snowflake/

Comment: @Sriga that's the first thing i did. same error... the uri is actually not necessary but that's beside the point.

Comment: From what I can see it looks like sqitch uses the snowSQL config file? or does it have its own file, if so, please check to make sure the account name in those files is only the information before the first "." in your Snowflake instance url.

Comment: @RachelMcGuigan - yes! that worked.  How did you know that sqitch uses the snowsql config file?  Was it in documentation or just tried it out?  Also, is there a way to indicate the account name with the sqitch init command if an account name isn't specified in the snowsql config file?  from the sqitch help init -> i'm not seeing an option to indicate account name

Comment: Vbp13 - in the second link that Sriga provided the "client" is "snowsql" from the  sqitch.conf file in the setup options. I did not see an account name in that file either. (lucky guess)

Comment: @RachelMcGuigan - do you want to submit an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, sounds like a defect in Sqitch. It complains if it can't find an account code, since without an account code one cannot connect to Snowflake. However, it should suppress that error when the command won't be connecting to Snowflake, as in the `init` command.

Here's a [bug report](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/issues/502); we should get it fixed before v1.0.1.

In the meantime, setting up the  [SnowSQL config file](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowsql-start.html#configuring-default-connection-settings) as mentioned in comments here is a decent workaround, but you can also set the `$SNOWSQL_ACCOUNT` environment variable, e.g.,

```
SNOWSQL_ACCOUNT=xxx ./t/sqitch init foo --engine snowflake
```

Answer (score 1):

Sriga provided the documentation for this answer [viewed here](http://sqitch.org/docs/manual/sqitchtutorial-snowflake).

However, to answer your question, to determine the account name, the SnowSQL configuration file needs to be set. To do this you will need to follow the guide on how to set up SnowSQL on the computer establishing a connection to Snowflake.

- [SnowSQL config File](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowsql-config.html#snowsql-config-file)

Make sure you also follow the steps to connect with Sqitch with the documentation provided in the beginning of this post.

Comment: specifically, you need to make sure the "accountname" is set in the config... Unfortunately, the sqitch documentation does not state that it uses the snowsql config.  It also doesn't state that the accountname must be set in the config.  Sqitch also does not allow you to set the account name in the command.

Comment: That is weird - can you confirm if that worked? If not, I would like to reach out to the document author.

Comment: What would you like me to confirm?

Comment: Were you still running into the error that account name cannot be determined when setting the snowsql config file?

Comment: 1) create a snowsql config file with no default values -> snowsql works because as part of the command you can specify -a MYACCCOUNTNAME -> however, if the accountname property is not set in the snowql config -> sqitch will NOT work.  
2) set the "accountname" property in the snowsql config--> sqitch will work.  

                   Summary
1) It would be helpful if the documentation stated this  
2) It would be even better if sqitch allowed you to indicate the account name as part of the CLI command, similar to how snowsql does.

Comment: since you were the first to help me to the solution, I'd like to accept your answer.  If you don't mind, can you please add the details about requiring accountname being set in the config?

Comment: vbp13 -apologies in the delay in response, I was getting carried away in python. I actually heard back from the maintainer of the documentation and they are addressing it here:https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/issues/502

Comment: Great. Let me know if you have a chance to update your answer so I can accept it.